# How to get exact Row Number of Clone Row using in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have created clone rows of a GridView in my Asp.net Project using javascript like this

```
function CreateGrid() {
            var Grid = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>')
            for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                var newrow = Grid.rows[Grid.rows.length - 1].cloneNode(true);
                newrow.cells[0].innerText;
                newrow.cells[1].children[0].value = '';
                newrow.cells[2].children[0].value = '';
                Grid.appendChild(newrow);
            }
        }
```

and Here is my GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
            CellPadding="4">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onclick="GetRowIndex(this)"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

I want that when I click on any cell it gives me the exact row number let's say when I click on cell of 3rd row it returns 3. So I write this function

```
function GetRowIndex(node) {
            var row = node.parentNode.parentNode;
            alert(row.rowIndex);
        }
```

But when I am clicking on any row instead of 1st row it always returns -1
Please help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your code and it works fine in IE8 and Firefox (Developer edition), but it doesn't work in Chrome.

It turns that your `Grid.appendChild(newrow);` line **is adding the row to the `<table>` element**, but you should **add the row to the `<body>` element**.

It's weird that it works fine in the first and second browser, but not in the third.

So, just change this

```
Grid.appendChild(newrow);
```

to this

```
Grid.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].appendChild(newrow);
```

now, you are adding your rows to the body, where it corresponds